# Accessing parent variables KIVY

Tags: python, kivy

I have some problems with kivy inheritance. So, I have ScreenManager root widget, and I want to access it's values inside my screen widget. Idea is to create a list of objects inside my ScreenManager, and the inherits it's values to the children widgets.

Code below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty, DictProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

from os import listdir
import requests
import json

kv_path = './kv/'
for kv in listdir(kv_path):
    Builder.load_file(kv_path + kv)


class MirSniffer(ScreenManager):
    mir_list = ListProperty()
    mir_dict = DictProperty({'MiR_S161': '10.173.175.117',
                         'MiR_S162': '10.173.175.121',
                         'MiR_S319': '10.173.175.120',
                         'MiR_S325': '10.173.175.119',
                         'MiR_S326': '10.173.175.116',
                         'MiR_S327': '10.173.175.118'
                         })

class MiR():
    """Defining a robot class"""

    error = 'Not accessible!'
    mode = 'Not accessible!'
    mission = 'Not accessible!'
    battery_per = 'Not accessible!'
    status = 'Not accessible!'

    def __init__(self, name, ip):
        self.name = name
        self.ip = ip

    def status_check(self):
        url = f"http://{self.ip}/api/v2.0.0/status"

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'authorization': "Basic YWRtaW46OGM2OTc2ZTViNTQxMDQxNWJkZTkwOGJkNGRlZTE1ZGZiMTY3YTljODczZmM0YmI4YTgxZjZmMmFiNDQ4YTkxOA==",
            'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
            'Postman-Token': "bfcd7159-1d12-5b7f-468f-d5e096709cbd"
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, timeout=2)
        text = json.loads(response.text)  # str to dict

        self.error = text["errors"][0]["description"]
        self.battery_per = text.get("battery_percentage")
        self.mission = text.get("mission_text")
        self.mode = text.get("mode_text")
        self.status = text.get("state_text")

    def creating_robots_list(mir_list, mir_dict):
        """Creating list of robots. Called once"""
        for key in mir_dict.keys():
            robot = MiR(key, mir_dict.get(key))
            mir_list.append(robot)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.creating_robots_list(self.mir_list, 
        self.mir_dict), 10)

class MainScreen(Screen):


        status_mir161 = StringProperty('0')

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.change_robot_status, 5)

        def change_robot_status(self, *args):
            test_string = self.status_mir161 + '1'
            self.status_mir161 = test_string


class Mir161(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MirSniffer()


if __name__ == '__main__':
     MainApp().run()
```

If I want to change self.status_mir161 according to mir_list - what's the syntax for it?

I'm not sure even if creating list of objects in the parent widget is proper approach.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your KV file but if you just want to access the `ScreenManager`'s values which you defined then first get the child's parent,so..on your `MainScreen`:

```
parent = self.parent
```

Then if that parent is the `ScreenManager`,you can then do something like:

```
target_dict = parent.mir_dict
```

I didn't test this but try this then we can take it from there